# CORS error when request made to spring boot oauth2 resource server from React client running on different address

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, configuration

This is an oauth2 resource server. I get the correct behavior when I pass the oauth token via postman request. Error I get in react client :

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/folders' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

My config:

```
@Configuration
public class CorsConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**").
                allowedOrigins("*");
            }
        };
    }
}

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

}
```

In spring console logs I get  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Failed to authorize filter invocation [OPTIONS /folders] with attributes [authenticated] while it succeeds in the postman request.

I expect for this config to be enough to not give cors error, the same config followed in many stackoverflow answers/tutorials. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure CORS with your resource-server `SecurityFilterChain` @Bean (instead of exposing a `WebMvcConfigurer`):

```java
http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
```

with

```java
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final var configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:3000"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));

        final var source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);

        return source;
    }
```

Also, make sure that this configuration is loaded with a breakpoint or a log line.

Sample taken from [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials), where you can also find samples using my starters enabling to set most security configuration (including CORS) from properties only (no Java conf necessary in most cases).

Comment: thanks for answering, but still the same error :(

Comment: You should double check and compare your conf with the [complete sample](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken) I pointed, because it works for me. Or provide with your complete sample...

Comment: P.S. when I write that "it works for me", I mean that I can query this samples and tutorials from an Angular app, which makes no difference with your case (regarding CORS, only allowed origin port changes as I kept default for Angular dev server: 4200)

Comment: I can't solve it! Please have a look at the config https://github.com/akhutail/MailMessaging

Comment: I don't understand why you have `spring-boot-starter-webflux` in a servlet application. Also you are creating a new project with a pretty old boot version (2.5). As I wont setup your all stack, I created a PR for you to try with `spring-boot-starter-web` and boot 3. Good luck.